# Test : Argument Expected

Tags: shell, unix

I am working on a shell script and I am getting an error saying Test : Argument expected. Its basically a sed command followed by checking if there were any errors

Please find the below

```
sed "s|${var1}|${var2}|g" $FILE_PATH$FILE_NAME > /tmp/$FILE_NAME

if [ "$command_error" != 0 ] ; then
        date
        echo "Error $command_error reading file $WS_FILE"
        echo "File Does not exist or is not readable"
        exit 30
fi
```

Comment: ignore the double quotes around command error

Comment: Why would `$command_error` be anything other than the empty string? Where is it set? Apart from that, comparing to an integer should use `-ne` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Hi, I am new to shell scripting. So does that mean that i need to set the sed command to $command_error. If so, i get an error as =sed not found . I had set it as :   $command_error=sed "s|${var1}|${var2}|g" $FILE_PATH$FILE_NAME > /tmp/$FILE_NAME

Comment: Do you want to check the exit status of the last command? If so, you can look at the special parameter `$?`. Do you want to assign the output of your sed command to a parameter? If so, use `varname="$(sed ...)"`. And read a good tutorial, such as [this one](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) or [this one](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/).

Answer (score 1):

What shell are you using?

I think you are missing a line:

```
command_error=$?
```

between the two blocks.
Be aware that many (all?) commands (eg echo $?) will actually change it's value.  Therefore, it's a good idea to assign $? to a temporary variable like this.